# MySQL LEFT JOIN issue: Retrieve workshops names in column A and a row id in column B

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies for the rubbish question title, but it's a bit tricky to summarise my requirement into a single line. I usually don't have an issue with MySQL JOINs but this one is throwing me.

I'm building a training feedback system and for one feature would like to display a list of all available workshops in the database, which workshops a given delegate has been assigned to and whether any feedback has been submitted by that delegate for those assigned workshops.

I could do this in a couple of queries, but I'm trying to do something a bit more elegant with a single query.

The pertinent details of my database structure:

`WORKSHOPS` table

- id: INT
- name: TINYTEXT

`DELEGATES` table

- id: INT
- name: TINYTEXT

`FEEDBACK` table

- delegate_id: INT
- workshop_id: INT
- feedback: TEXT

`DELEGATES_X_WORKSHOPS` table

- delegate_id: INT
- workshop_id: INT

**delegate_id** and **workshop_id** in the tables are Foreign Keys to the `DELEGATES` and `WORKSHOPS` tables.

As any given delegate can be assigned to multiple workshops, I'm using the `DELEGATES_X_WORKSHOPS` table as a cross-referencing table so I can quickly search for who is assigned to any given workshop or which workshops any given delegate is assigned to.

However, I've tried LEFT JOINing a couple of different ways and I can't get a full list of workshops on the left and matches (if they exist) on the right for a given delegate_id.

**Example data**
Delegate **Ross** has delegate_id = 1
Registered workshops are

- C++
- PHP
- ASP.NET
- HTML5
- JavaScript

Ross is assigned to PHP, HTML5 and JavaScript

Question 1 is this: how do I return the following for delegate_id=1:

```
[workshop] | [assigned]
C++        | null
PHP        | TRUE
ASP.NET    | null
HTML5      | TRUE
JavaScript | TRUE
```

(it doesn't matter right now what goes into column B, I just want a null if a particular delegate_id hasn't been assigned to a workshop).

I've used this:

```
SELECT
  workshops.name,
  delegates_x_workshops.delegate_id
FROM
  workshops
LEFT JOIN
  delegates_x_workshops
ON
  workshops.id=delegates_x_workshops.workshop_id
WHERE
  delegates_x_workshops.delegate_id=1
```

However I'm only returning the 3 rows where delegate_id=1, not 5 rows for all workshops.

Question 2 is a bit more involved:
Taking question 1 as a base, how would I work column C to display if feedback has been left for a workshop that Ross has been assigned to?

```
[workshop] | [assigned] | [givenfeedback]
C++        | null       | null
PHP        | TRUE       | TRUE
ASP.NET    | null       | null
HTML5      | TRUE       | null
JavaScript | TRUE       | TRUE
```

Thanks in advance to anybody who makes it this far and has a clue what I'm blithering about. As I said, I could rattle through this with a few different queries, but I'm trying to keep things elegant.

No doubt half of this will need clarification, so ask any questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1, you need to move the `where` condition into the `on` clause.  It is turning the `left outer join` into an `inner join` because non-matching rows have `NULL` values:

```
SELECT w.name, dxw.delegate_id
FROM workshops w LEFT JOIN
     delegates_x_workshops dxw
     ON w.id = dxw.workshop_id and
        dxw.delegate_id = 1;
```

For the second question, I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT w.name,
       (case when max(w.name = 'Ross') > 0 then 'True' end) as Assigned,
       (case when count(f.workshop_id) > 0 then 'True' end) as Feedback
FROM workshops w LEFT JOIN
     delegates_x_workshops dxw
     ON w.id = dxw.workshop_id and
        dxw.delegate_id = 1 LEFT JOIN
     delegates d
     on d.id = dxw.delegate_id LEFT JOIN
     feedback f
     on f.workshop_id = w.id
GROUP BY w.name;
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could use multiple joining conditions. Should give me a good head-start on sorting question 2 myself - thanks Gordon

Comment: My awful description has introduced complexity where none was required, so I don't need the logic switching you've put into Assigned and Feedback. All that was required was a second join to check the feedback table with the AND condition on the join. You're a star Gordon, thank you!

Comment: I've marked as suitable answer, but can't upvote because I don't have sufficient rep.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's my final query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  workshops.id AS wid,
  workshops.name AS workshop,
  (delegates_x_workshops.delegate_id IS NOT NULL) AS assigned,
  (initial_feedback.delegate_id IS NOT NULL
   OR
   ongoing_feedback.delegate_id IS NOT NULL) AS hasfeedback
FROM
  workshops
LEFT JOIN
  delegates_x_workshops
ON
  workshops.id = delegates_x_workshops.workshop_id
AND
  delegates_x_workshops.delegate_id = 1
LEFT JOIN
  initial_feedback
ON
  workshops.id = initial_feedback.workshop_id
AND
  initial_feedback.delegate_id = 1
LEFT JOIN
  ongoing_feedback
ON
  workshops.id = ongoing_feedback.workshop_id
AND
  ongoing_feedback.delegate_id = 1
ORDER BY
  workshop ASC
```

For every workshop in the `WORKSHOPS` table, I'll get the id and name of the workshop, 1 or 0 if a given delegate_id is assigned and 1 or 0 if feedback of either type (I have 2 kinds) has been left for that workshop.

Scary to think that all I was missing was an `AND` condition on my `LEFT JOIN`.

Thanks again Gordon!